# git pull / push returns: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: _

Tags: linux, git, fatal-error, git-push, git-pull

When I run `$git push` or `$git pull dev master`, I received this error:

> fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:  _

I searched and found this solution:

```
ssh <host> git-receive-pack <path-to-git-repository>
```

I ran it. Here is the server response:

```
00..4b29e780 refs/heads/master report- 
status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet ofs-delta agent=git/1.8.3.1
00..4b29e780 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
00..4b29e780 refs/remotes/origin/master
0000
```

What does it mean? What is the problem?

Comment: Please specify if you are running on Windows, Linux, or OSX

Comment: @Arount Git server is GNU/Linux

Comment: There's nothing obvious in your `ssh` output here. You might run it through a viewer that checks for "invisible" control characters though. The usual culprit is a bad `.bashrc` or `.profile` or similar file that outputs some text even though the shell being run is non-interactive, but usually the text is more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of a `ssh git@YourServer`

Generally, it is some kind of welcome message (as a Git server should disallow an interactive session).

But if you see any other output *before* that welcome message, that would explain any Git error when using SSH. As commented, check the resources files for that account do *not* output any text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks VonC, you help solve my problem.
My error was in origin url.
origin was set to

```
git remote set-url origin http://192.168.1.88:7990/scm/web/t_new.git
```

Then I always get error, like this:

> $ git push -u origin master
>       Uploading LFS objects: 100% (25924/25924), 22 GB | 0 B/s, done
>       Enumerating objects: 114248, done.
>       Counting objects: 100% (114248/114248), done.
>       Compressing objects: 100% (98480/98480), done.
>       fatal: protocol error: bad line length 81925 MiB | 311.97 MiB/s
>       fatal: sha1 file '' write error: Broken pipe
>       error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.1.88:7990/scm/web/t_new.git'

When i change it begin work like charm.

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@192.168.1.88:7999/web/t_new.git
```

By the way LFS is enabled. Server is Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a file `/etc/ssh/sshrc` with contents `/usr/bin/beep` on the ssh server, removing this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My url is like

```
ssh://user@domain.com:1234/var/repository.git
```

An i received :

**fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: user**

All is need to do is set the environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND with the ssh command and port param before push :

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -p 1234 " git push origin master
```

Also, you can set this command globally with :

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -p 1234 "
```

I think last space after "1234 " is not needed.